# Nested CSS Div and Span Styles Not Working

Tags: css, html

I can't seem to understand why certain span properties (in particular, the width and text-align of "controller-row-number" and "controller-row-name"):

```
#controller {
    width: 250px;
    float: left;

    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
}

.controller-row {
    background-color: blue;
}

.controller-row-number {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 60px;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}

.controller-row-name {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Are being ignored in the following code:

```
<div id="controller">
    <div class="controller-row">
        <span class="controller-row-number">1</span>
        <span class="controller-row-name">First Name</span>
    </div>

    <div class="controller-row">
        <span class="controller-row-number">2</span>
        <span class="controller-row-name">Second Name</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a JSFiddle located here:

http://jsfiddle.net/WZFJD

Can anyone point me to the correct edits to make, so that the styles are adhered?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`display: inline-block;` to the rescue !

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/WZFJD/1/)

```
.controller-row-number {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}

.controller-row-name {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

`span` elements are by default inline, so you have to make them block, or inline-block if you want your width rule to be applied, otherwise they just take up enough width to fit. The width and height of `display: inline;` elems cannot be set as you tried to do. Tho you can fake the height using `line-height`.

Comment: As an added explanation: `<span>` is an inline element to contain text, thus can't be given a height or width and some other styling you are used to for divs. `display:inline-block` fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

Spans are displayed as `inline` by default, if you want to specify a width you'll have to set `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

`width` cannot be applied to an `inline` element like a `<span>`. You will have to also style your spans of class `controller-row-number` and `controller-row-name` to be `display: inline-block`